# Lumen API CORS Ajax 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: reactjs, rest, axios, lumen

I have an api on Laravel Lumen, we test via Postman and Ruby Rest Client and all go very well, but we create a simple Auth Login that response a web token, all works fine but on our React App actually we have this "405 405 Method Not Allowed".

We create a class with the next code:

```
<?php namespace palanik\lumen\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class LumenCors {

    protected $settings = array(
                'origin' => '*',    // Wide Open!
                'allowMethods' => 'GET,HEAD,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',
                );

    protected function setOrigin($req, $rsp) {
        $origin = $this->settings['origin'];
        if (is_callable($origin)) {
            // Call origin callback with request origin
            $origin = call_user_func($origin,
                                    $req->header("Origin")
                                    );
        }
        $rsp->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $origin);
    }

    protected function setExposeHeaders($req, $rsp) {
        if (isset($this->settings['exposeHeaders'])) {
            $exposeHeaders = $this->settings['exposeHeaders'];
            if (is_array($exposeHeaders)) {
                $exposeHeaders = implode(", ", $exposeHeaders);
            }

            $rsp->header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', $exposeHeaders);
        }
    }

    protected function setMaxAge($req, $rsp) {
        if (isset($this->settings['maxAge'])) {
            $rsp->header('Access-Control-Max-Age', $this->settings['maxAge']);
        }
    }

    protected function setAllowCredentials($req, $rsp) {
        if (isset($this->settings['allowCredentials']) && $this->settings['allowCredentials'] === True) {
            $rsp->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
        }
    }

    protected function setAllowMethods($req, $rsp) {
        if (isset($this->settings['allowMethods'])) {
            $allowMethods = $this->settings['allowMethods'];
            if (is_array($allowMethods)) {
                $allowMethods = implode(", ", $allowMethods);
            }

            $rsp->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', $allowMethods);
        }
    }

    protected function setAllowHeaders($req, $rsp) {
        if (isset($this->settings['allowHeaders'])) {
            $allowHeaders = $this->settings['allowHeaders'];
            if (is_array($allowHeaders)) {
                $allowHeaders = implode(", ", $allowHeaders);
            }
        }
        else {  // Otherwise, use request headers
            $allowHeaders = $req->header("Access-Control-Request-Headers");
        }

        if (isset($allowHeaders)) {
            $rsp->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', $allowHeaders);
        }
    }

    protected function setCorsHeaders($req, $rsp) {

        // http://www.html5rocks.com/static/images/cors_server_flowchart.png
        // Pre-flight
        if ($req->isMethod('OPTIONS')) {
            $this->setOrigin($req, $rsp);
            $this->setMaxAge($req, $rsp);
            $this->setAllowCredentials($req, $rsp);
            $this->setAllowMethods($req, $rsp);
            $this->setAllowHeaders($req, $rsp);
        }
        else {
            $this->setOrigin($req, $rsp);
            $this->setExposeHeaders($req, $rsp);
            $this->setAllowCredentials($req, $rsp);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

        if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS')) {
            $response = new Response("", 200);
        }
        else {
            $response = $next($request);
        }

        $this->setCorsHeaders($request, $response);

        return $response;
    }

}
```

We add on bootstrap/app.php

```
$app->routeMiddleware([
    'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'cors' => palanik\lumen\Middleware\LumenCors::class,
]);
```

And our route:

```
$app->group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function($app)
{
    $app->post('/auth/login', function() {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'CORS OPTIONS Accepted.',
        ]);
    });
});
```

With our rest clients all goes fine but how i said on our React js app because the browser send an OPTIONS, the request doesn't pass to the POST.

Our Recat Axios request:

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'URL',
    data: {
            email: 'Fred',
            password: 'Flintstone'
    }
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Error con React log:
The problem is that OPTIONS is send before POST for the browser.
Headers response:
    HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
    Allow: POST
    Cache-Control: no-cache, private
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    Date: Sun, 29 Oct 2017 01:30:34 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
    transfer-encoding: chunked
    Connection: keep-alive

What are we missing on our API?

Regards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before sending the original request, the web browser sends a request of Http method Options which checks if cross-domain requests are accepted at the API server?

Below is the approach I followed:

Add wildcard route of method `option`

```
Route::options(
    '/{any:.*}', 
    [
        'middleware' => ['CorsMiddleware'], 
        function (){ 
            return response(['status' => 'success']); 
        }
    ]
);
```

`CorsMiddleware` is the middleware used to handle the requests.

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class CorsMiddleware
{
    protected $settings = array(
        'origin' => '*',    // Wide Open!
        'allowMethods' => 'GET,HEAD,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',
    );

    protected function setOrigin($req, $rsp) {
        $origin = $this->settings['origin'];
        if (is_callable($origin)) {
            // Call origin callback with request origin
            $origin = call_user_func($origin,
                        $req->header("Origin")
                    );
        }
        $rsp->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $origin);
    }

    protected function setExposeHeaders($req, $rsp) {
        if (isset($this->settings['exposeHeaders'])) {
            $exposeHeaders = $this->settings['exposeHeaders'];
            if (is_array($exposeHeaders)) {
                $exposeHeaders = implode(", ", $exposeHeaders);
            }
            
            $rsp->header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', $exposeHeaders);
        }
    }

    protected function setMaxAge($req, $rsp) {
        if (isset($this->settings['maxAge'])) {
            $rsp->header('Access-Control-Max-Age', $this->settings['maxAge']);
        }
    }

    protected function setAllowCredentials($req, $rsp) {
        if (isset($this->settings['allowCredentials']) && $this->settings['allowCredentials'] === True) {
            $rsp->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
        }
    }

    protected function setAllowMethods($req, $rsp) {
        if (isset($this->settings['allowMethods'])) {
            $allowMethods = $this->settings['allowMethods'];
            if (is_array($allowMethods)) {
                $allowMethods = implode(", ", $allowMethods);
            }
            
            $rsp->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', $allowMethods);
        }
    }

    protected function setAllowHeaders($req, $rsp) {
        if (isset($this->settings['allowHeaders'])) {
            $allowHeaders = $this->settings['allowHeaders'];
            if (is_array($allowHeaders)) {
                $allowHeaders = implode(", ", $allowHeaders);
            }
        }
        else {  // Otherwise, use request headers
            $allowHeaders = $req->header("Access-Control-Request-Headers");
        }
        if (isset($allowHeaders)) {
            $rsp->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', $allowHeaders);
        }
    }
    
    protected function setCorsHeaders($req, $rsp) {
        // http://www.html5rocks.com/static/images/cors_server_flowchart.png
        // Pre-flight
        if ($req->isMethod('OPTIONS')) {
            $this->setOrigin($req, $rsp);
            $this->setMaxAge($req, $rsp);
            $this->setAllowCredentials($req, $rsp);
            $this->setAllowMethods($req, $rsp);
            $this->setAllowHeaders($req, $rsp);
        }
        else {
            $this->setOrigin($req, $rsp);
            $this->setExposeHeaders($req, $rsp);
            $this->setAllowCredentials($req, $rsp);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS')) {
            $response = new Response("", 200);
        }
        else {
            $response = $next($request);
        }
        $this->setCorsHeaders($request, $response);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Load middleware `$app->routeMiddleware` section of `bootstrap/app.php`

Keep all application URLs in the group checking the `CorsMiddleware`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'CorsMiddleware'], function($router){
    $app->post('/auth/login', function() {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'CORS OPTIONS Accepted.',
        ]);
    });
}
```

Comment: This answer has been applied OK in Lumen 5.5

Comment: That actually works!!! Thanks a lot, we try a lot of another options and libraries but this is simple and works.

Comment: The answer is very useful, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found a clean way for it. Just add the following lines to the `.htaccess` (If you don't know, `.htaccess` has been located at `public/.htaccess`):

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
</IfModule>
```

Then, define a route in your Laravel/Lumen application like this:

```
Route::options('/{any:.*}', function() { return response(['status' => 'success']); });};
```

Of course you need `mod-rewrite` and `mod-headers`. You can enable them (if not already enabled) using the following commands (Ubuntu):

```
a2enmod rewrite
a2enmod headers
systemctl reload apache2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add simple OPTIONS handler that should be return 200 code
Here a useful example to integrate:

https://gist.github.com/danharper/06d2386f0b826b669552

Comment: I tried that but now i get "301 Moved Permanently" but on the others works fine.